# Edit and save pgn files with SCID

Tags: pgn, scid

In SCID, how can I edit a pgn file and save to a new file after I modified it?

For example below, I have deleted some games in the 'game list' panel. But when I do `Database - Export all filter games`, it still saves all games to a new file.

[image: Deleted some games]

Answer (score 2):

Oh I got it...

'Delete' game has no effect. I need to do 'Filter -- Remove game' and then export filtered games